# Unit Test to see if class methods are defined

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I simply want to test if my class methods are defined, e.g.:

```
export class GoalSettingsPage {

    public goal: Goal;

    constructor(
    ) {
        this.goal = this.navParams.get('goal');
    }

    saveForm(event) {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.goal);
    }
```

Unit Test sth like:

```
xit('should have methods defined', () => {

    let g = new Goal()
    let np = new NavParams()
    let vc = new ViewController()
    let e = new Events()
    let fb = new FormBuilder()

    let settingModal = new GoalSettingsPage(np,vc,fb,e);

    expect (settingModal.saveForm(e).toBeDefined;
})
```

Isn't working.

Comment: Why is `settingModal.saveForm(e)` being called? To check its existence, it shoudn't. Btw, there is a syntax error, which test runner should warn you about.

Comment: Then how to check its existence?

Comment: `expect(settingModal.saveForm).toBeDefined()`

Comment: Worked. Write as an answer I give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the existence of a method in class instance it should be

```
expect(settingModal.saveForm).toBeDefined()
```

Or, more precisely,

```
expect(settingModal.saveForm).toBe(jasmine.any(Function));
```